# Amazon EC2 Instance Volume Size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to launch an EC2 instance in AWS. While configuring the storage it asks me for "Size (GiB)". What is the free tier limit of this size? I want to launch t2.medium instance so what is the limit of the free size for it? For example if I put 40 as value there will I get charged more? I am learning deployment process hence it can be a novice question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a free storage limit of 30gb in a t2.micro instance, so when using a larger value, you'll be charged.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

The only free tier eligible EC2 instance size is the t2.micro, so yes, if you launch an t2.medium you will be charged.

http://aws.amazon.com/free/

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of the charge for t2.medium that is $0.052 per Hour. So do you say that I can put any volume size (say 40) and I will be charged $0.052 per Hour and nothing for the volume size?